# Azure AD Authorization issue with c# code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I want to create Azure Resource Groups through C# code.

I have followed all steps of Creating Service Principal from this link  and access still i am getting error

I am following these links

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/csharp
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal

Below is the error

Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The client 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' with object id 'XXXXXXXXXXXX' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/write' over scope '/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXX/resourcegroups/Zimmergren.ARM.ResourceGroupDemo-123'.
  Source=Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.ResourceGroupsOperations.d__7.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.ResourceGroupsOperationsExtensions.d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.ResourceGroupsOperationsExtensions.CreateOrUpdate(IResourceGroupsOperations operations, String resourceGroupName, ResourceGroup parameters)
   at AzureAD.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\nitin\Downloads\AzureAD\AzureAD\AzureAD\Program.cs:line 48

Answer (score 0):

> Message=The client 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' with object id 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
>   does not have authorization to perform action
>   'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/write' over scope
>   '/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXX/resourcegroups/Zimmergren.ARM.ResourceGroupDemo-123'.

The reason you're getting this error is because the `Service Pricipal` you created does not have permission to perform `Create Resource Group` operation in your Azure Subscription.

What you would need to do is assign a role to this `Service Principal` that has permission to perform this operation. To start with, you can assign `Contributor` role at the `Subscription` level to this `Service Principal`.

You can do it through `Azure Portal`, `PowerShell Cmdlets` or `CLI Tools`. You may find this link helpful in doing this through Azure Portal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i have already added contributor role.. still facing same issue

Comment: Did you make this Service Principal a Contributor at subscription level?

Comment: Yes. Once i click on Azure AD -> Find a User -> Searched by the same User -> Azure Resources. Then i could see my subscription as Contributor  Role. What else shall i do ?

Comment: Instead assign the role to the user, you need to assign the corresponding the role to **service principal**, please check the link mentioned by GauravMantri